# Flask: OperationalError: unable to open database file (in memory data base file)

Tags: python, apache, flask, sqlite

I want to create shared in-memory data base in one program(`main.py`) and want to connect to it from flask application(`check_flask.py`) program which runninng through apache server.
I am successfully creating in-memory shared data base in `main.py` and but it gives  `OperationalError: unable to open database file`  error when i am trying to connect to it in Flask application program(`check_flask.py`)

Here is my Code:

main.py

```
p = sqlite3.connect("file:fruits?mode=memory&cache=shared")
p.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar, baz)')
p.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('apple', 'orange')")
p.commit()
```

check_flask.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_first_request
def Initialization():
     q = sqlite3.connect("file:fruits?mode=memory&cache=shared")
     print list(q.execute('SELECT * FROM foo'))
```

Giving `OperationalError: unable to open database file` error

But i am succsfully connecting to fruits in-memory data base from the another program (check.py) which is not flask based.

check.py

```
q = sqlite3.connect("file:fruits?mode=memory&cache=shared")
print list(q.execute('SELECT * FROM foo'))
```

and it is printing the result as `[(u'apple', u'orange')]`

I have gone through many websites, but none of them seem to be working.

Please Help!

Thank you

Comment: might the issue be the following:  check_flask contains @app.before_first_request, therefor tries to read from db before it is even created and updated with values?

Comment: @gittert After running main.py only i am running Flask application program(check_flask.py)

Comment: sorry, for a minute I thought it was all within the same flask app. I noticed you run flask app with Apache. For testing purposes, if you run the flask app with its built-in server in debug mode, does that make any difference?

Comment: @gittert I think so.I am thinking it may be the path problem.Not sure

Comment: I think it is about permissions or access if serving by apache. That is why I would test with the built-in server first.

Comment: i will check it out

Comment: @gittert I gave the Permissions,But no use

Comment: did you run it with flask built-in server?

Comment: I run flask application with apache server

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple different processes with a single in-memory database?

Comment: Also, the standard python sqlite bindings only turn on URL filename support if you explicitly request it with an extra parameter to `connect()`. Are you sure you don't have a file named `file:fruits?mode=memory&cache=shared` lying around somewhere? That would explain why you seem to think multiple processes can use the same in-memory db. They're actually using a file db, and your flask process isn't using the same working directory so it can't see the same one as the other processes.